# Как сделать чтобы при открытии сайта хедер и футер разъезжались и открывали основной контент?

Tags: javascript, вёрстка, frontend

Как можно реализовать чтобы *хедер* и *футер* при открытии сайта разъезжались от середины экрана и прижимались (*хедер* к верху, а *футер* к низу)?

Подскажите, какие библиотечки глянуть, буду рад ссылкам!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSBIN: https://jsbin.com/saxuwi/2/edit?html,css,js,output

```
header {
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
  background: #ddd;
}

main {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0px;
  -moz-transition: 1s;
  -ms-transition: 1s;
  -o-transition: 1s;
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  transition: 1s;
}

.shown main {
  max-height: 1000px;
}

footer {
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
  background: #bbb;
}
```

UPDATE:

Если нужно именно из центра:

JSBIN: https://jsbin.com/nozicu/7/edit?html,css,js,output

Stylus:

```
body
  height 100%

main
  height 100%
  padding 100px

header
  display block
  position absolute
  height 50%
  width 100%
  background #aaa
  transition 1s

footer
  display block
  position absolute
  top 50%
  height 50%
  width 100%
  background black
  transition 1s

.shown
  header
    height 50px
  footer
    height 50px
    top 100%
    margin-top -50px
```

Если необходимо сделать хидер и футер узкими полосками, то залейте их фоном и внутри разместите нужной высоты блоки, прилепленные к краю: (`header .container { position: absolute; bottom: 0; height 30px; width 100%; }`);

Comment: обновил, заметив что автору нужно из центра открывать.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать JQuery.animate и, к примеру, изменять ширину блока с контентом

```
$(function(){
    $('.content').animate({
        height: "300px"
    }, 5000);    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2c8hcg1r/5/
или использовать css свойство transition
http://htmlbook.ru/css/transition
может быть вот эту библиотеку css анимаций можно задействовать
http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/